# Mongo issues when trying to look at my collection using .find()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So to start off first ill display my code that i have so far.

```
var express = require("express"), 
        app = express(),
 bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
   mongoose = require("mongoose");


   mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/yelp_camp");

  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
  app.set("view engine","ejs");

var chairSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    image:String,
    price:Number
});

var data =mongoose.model("data",chairSchema);
data.create(
{
  partname:"short cylinder",
  img:"http://www.needforseatusa.com/assets/images/products/replacement%20parts/short_cylinder_thumbnail.jpg",
  price:14.90
},function(err,chair){
  if (err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  else{
    console.log("newly created chair");
    console.log(data);
  }

}


);
```

so my issue is when I run my app using "node app.js" it is suppose to create a database and a collection called datas and inside there should be like data that looks similar to the object i am creating in the data.create function call but when i go to check my collection inside the db of yelp_camp all i get back is this sort of list

```
{"id" : ObjectId("3453453453453463456353sdsfdsf"),"price":14.9,"_v":0)
```

so i thought if i run .pretty() it might change but it remains the same i feel like i have a tiny error somewhere but I just do not see it

Answer (score 0):

In your `schema` you have wrote `name` and `image`, but while saving you are using `partname` and `img`. thats why you are getting this behaviour.

```
var chairSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,//<-look here
    image:String,//<-look here
    price:Number
});
```

while creating new `document`, you need to use same exact fieldname.

```
data.create(
{
  //partname:"short cylinder",
  //name should be used instead of partname
  name:"short cylinder",
  //img:"http://www.needforseatusa.com/assets/images/products/replacement%20parts/
  //'img' should not be used, 'image' should be used instead.
  image:"http://www.needforseatusa.com/assets/images/products/replacement%20parts/short_cylinder_thumbnail.jpg",
  price:14.90
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right. but if you are not giving same name as your schema object name then it will only not be able to save those properties. In anycase  pretty() function have to work in mongodb shell (if the document have been saved).